# Ruby Unit-testin, wrong numer of failures shown

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

Situation is simple. I have a module like this(first.rb):

```
def ret_s(l)
  return "one" if l == 1
  return "twoe" if l == 2
  return "threee" if l == 3
end


def ret_l(str)
  return 1 if str == "one" 
  return 2 if str == "two"  
  return 4 if str == "three" 
end
```

and a testing class(TestFist.rb):

```
require 'test/unit'
require './first'

class TestFirst < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_fist

    assert_equal("one",ret_s(1))
    assert_equal("two",ret_s(2))
    assert_equal("three",ret_s(3))
  end

  def test_second

    assert_equal(1,ret_l("one"))
    assert_equal(2,ret_l("two"))
    assert_equal(3,ret_l("three"))
  end

end
```

When running this test, why do I get an answer like this:

```
$ ruby TestFirst.rb
Run options:

# Running tests:

FF

Finished tests in 0.001000s, 2000.0000 tests/s, 5000.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_fist(TestFirst) [TestFirst.rb:9]:
<"two"> expected but was
<"twoe">.

  2) Failure:
test_second(TestFirst) [TestFirst.rb:17]:
<3> expected but was
<4>.

2 tests, 5 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

The last line makes me think that I'm doing something wrong. I would expect something like this:

2 tests, 6 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

not

2 tests, 5 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Answer (score 2):

The first test aborts after the first failed assertion, thus it never executes the line `assert_equal("three",ret_s(3))`

Comment: i know all this is about this test, but shouldn't assertion just register failure and go to the next one?

Comment: Not sure how you are defining "shouldn't". If you mean "defined behaviour", then no, it shouldn't since that's not how test suites work, all the ones I use abort after the first failed assertion. If you mean "logically correct behaviour", then I suppose that is up to each person. To me it makes sense: if I assert the returned user is the expected one and the emails match, but it turns out it's the wrong user, then there's no sense in also checking the emails. If they match it's pure coincidence, if they don't, it's just spam, the first assertion is the actual problem.